# PostgreSQL on Mac Catalina

Tags: postgresql, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install odoo on mac catalina 10.15 but i'm facing this problem while installing postgresql

Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

thanks for help in advance :-)

Comment: It's looking for the OpenJDK8 virtual machine which is not present at the location specified

Comment: @AlexW can you please tell me how, I'm beginer

Comment: What command did you try to run? Something with `apt install …`? Sounds like something in your install (of java) is broken when it search for the `apt` tool in a `JavaVirtualMachines` directory.

Comment: @MohamedAatef Please give more details about how you set up odoo and what steps you took that lead up to this error

Comment: I was useing "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: a@as-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo apt -get update
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
a@as-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo apt -get upgrade -y

Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
a@as-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Comment: You shouldn't be using `apt-get update` on a Macbook unless it's inside a Debian-based virtual machine.  This looks like it's trying to read a path on your Macbook hard drive which doesn't seem right.